# How KP Panchang is calculated

Tags: astrology, panchang, horary-astrology

I visit a KP calculator website stated below to get all the informations about KP sublords from moon planet. The website generates all sub-lords based on timing.

What is the formula to calculate the next moon's sub-lord planet from start to end time?

For example:

**Start Time - End Time - Sign - Star - Sublord**

**1PM - 2PM - Mercury - Mars - Ketu**

**2PM - 4PM - Mercury - Mars - Venus**

[Website: Ruling Planet Motion](https://www.rahasyavedicastrology.com/motion-chart/)